# Postgres Error when using Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, delayed-job

I've been trying to create a Delayed Job that checks if a product is still available on Etsy. I get an error whenever I run it with **bin/delayed_job start** (though for some reason it works fine with **rake jobs:work**). The error I get is:

```
Job CheckInventoryStatus (id=1174) FAILED (0 prior attempts) with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
            FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
              ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
           WHERE a.attrelid = '"spree_stock_items"'::regclass
             AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
           ORDER BY a.attnum
```

I believe the offending line is, where it first tries to do the SQL lookup of:

```
etsy_location = variant.stock_locations.where(vendor_type: 2).first
```

The full code is below.

```
CheckInventoryStatus = Struct.new(:empty) do
  def perform
    Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job.after_fork
    Spree::Variant.where('spree_variants.inventory_link != ?',"").each do |variant|
      begin
        page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(variant.inventory_link))
        etsy_location = variant.stock_locations.where(vendor_type: 2).first
        unless etsy_location.nil?
          if !page.at_xpath('//meta[@itemprop="availability"]/@content').nil?
            if etsy_location.count_on_hand(variant) <= 10
              etsy_location.restock(variant, 10-etsy_location.count_on_hand(variant))
            end
          else
            etsy_location.unstock(variant, etsy_location.count_on_hand(variant))
          end
        end
      rescue => error
        Delayed::Worker.logger.info "Error for "+variant.inventory_link
        Delayed::Worker.logger.info error.backtrace
      end
    end 
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: It's acting like the user you're running bin/delayed_job start with doesn't have permissions for the pg_attribute or related table.

Comment: My hunch is that its not loading your database.yml correctly. Try running with `RAILS_ENV`, e.g. `RAILS_ENV=development bin/delayed_job start`.

Comment: @apod, did you have any luck with this? I am also having weird Postgres errors with Delayed Job. As soon as I commented out part of my job that does HTTP downloads, the errors disappear. Try replacing your open() with a hard-coded string or a local file and see if that helps.

Comment: I haven't worked on this code in a while, but it looks like what I ended up doing is downloading the file and then opening the local file with Nokogiri. Sounds like basically what you suggest. Weird.